# Powershell search in text file for new content

Tags: powershell, match

I need your help. I want to search with Powershell through a log file to find if there is a new entry in the log file thats new or unknown. For this we have another text file with a pattern. What I want to find out is, if there is a line in the text file which does not match the pattern defined in the pattern text file. Any idea? I have tried with `Select-String * -match/-notmatch` but I don't get it running as described. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you try to create a [mcve] so we can recreate the situation better? How does the files look like? Show us the exact code you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the content of the log file into a variable:

```
$log = Get-Content c:\log.log
```

Import the match pattern into a variable:

```
$pattern = Get-Content c:\pattern.txt
```

Show log entries where each line does not match the pattern stored in the pattern variable:

```
$log | ? { $_ -notmatch $pattern }
```

Comment: Thanks thats helps me a lot!